# Javascript removeAttribute working in IE but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, getelementbyid

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('menuTest').style.removeAttribute('display')">
```

This is the code I'm using. Basically I'm trying to make an element visible only after everything else on the page has loaded. It works fine in IE, but not in Chrome. I don't work with Js much...but if I remember correctly, is there something finnicky about the getElementById function that I need to do?

Comment: `removeAttribute()` is for a DOM element, but `element.style` isn't a DOM element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('menuTest').style.removeProperty('display')">
```

Test page: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/tests/cssMisc.html#removeProperty

Comment: this messed it up in IE though (fixed in chrome, and works in firefox though!)...I'm going to try and run it through an if/else where it just uses removeAttribute in IE (since I know that works there)

Comment: Why would you remove it when you can set it with a correct value and not worry about browser versions?

Answer (score 1):

You do not use remove attribute with styles, you set it to the value needed.

```
document.getElementById('menuTest').style.display = "block"; //"inline"
```

Answer (score 0):

If your element has a CSS3 timed transition set on it in CSS, the javascript will also fail even if your code is correct. Because the element is transitioning when the javascript fires, it can not manipulate it in some browsers (Chrome is one). In these cases try delaying the javascript to fire after the transition has had time to finish rendering the element.